# xhtml2pdf, cyrillic characters don't work

Tags: python, html, pdf, pdf-generation, xhtml2pdf

I try to convert html to pdf. I use xhtml2pdf.
My code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from xhtml2pdf import pisa
sourceHtml = '<html>' \
             '    <head>' \
             '        <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">' \
             '    </head>' \
             '    <body>' \
             '        <p>Русский текст</p>' \
             '    </body>' \
             '</html>'

outputFilename = "test.pdf"

def convertHtmlToPdf(sourceHtml, outputFilename):
    resultFile = open(outputFilename, "w+b")
    pisaStatus = pisa.CreatePDF(sourceHtml, dest=resultFile)#, encoding='UTF-8')
    resultFile.close() 
    return pisaStatus.err

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pisa.showLogging()
    convertHtmlToPdf(sourceHtml, outputFilename)
```

PDF is created, but the Cyrillic characters are represented by black squares.
What I'm doing wrong? How to make it right?

Answer (score 3):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from xhtml2pdf import pisa
sourceHtml = '<html>' \
             '    <head>' \
             '        <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">' \
             '        <style type="text/css">' \
             '            @page { size: A4; margin: 1cm; }' \
             '            @font-face { font-family: Arial; src: url(/pathToTTF/arial.ttf); }' \
             '            p { color: red; font-family: Arial; }' \
             '        </style>' \
             '    </head>' \
             '    <body>' \
             '        <p>Русский текст</p>' \
             '    </body>' \
             '</html>'

outputFilename = "test.pdf"

def convertHtmlToPdf(sourceHtml, outputFilename):
    resultFile = open(outputFilename, "w+b")
    pisaStatus = pisa.CreatePDF(sourceHtml, dest=resultFile, encoding='UTF-8')
    resultFile.close() 
    return pisaStatus.err

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pisa.showLogging()
    convertHtmlToPdf(sourceHtml, outputFilename)
```

It works. I had to set test style to html tag.

Comment: What did you do exactly? You only added `<style>` tag?

Comment: Not only, in <style> I added next: @font-face { font-family: Arial; src: url(/pathToTTF/arial.ttf)

Comment: Maybe every font supporting cyrillic would work just fine. Thanks!